Can attacker recover private key if he have history of intermediate elliptic curve point coordinates?
It is known that elliptic curves are used in public-key cryptography.
Lets take for example secp256k1. Given private key $k$ and generator point $G$, we can get public key by performing elliptic curve point multiplication $k*G$.
It is known that simplest algorithm to get public key is to perform $k$ point additions. More advanced solutions involve point doubling, combined with point additions.
Can attacker recover private key if he know the algorithm and have the history of previous intermediate elliptic curve point coordinates, e.g. by using rainbow table? It reminds me an LCG that when it is being used as random number generator, it can be cracked given history of previous (or following) values to recover its parameters.
My guess for this question is that attacker should know (or find) order of operations (doubling, addition, or getting correct precomputed value by some index).

The best attack is the Pollord $\rho$ with $sqrt n$ complexity. If you know the order of operations this means that you know the private key.

"have the history of previous elliptic curve point coordinates" - hmmm, I interpreted that to mean "the previous public keys that have been generated"; Daniel S interpreted that to mean "the intermediate values of the addition chain".  Which meaning did you intend?

@poncho, indeed, question was ambiguous. I mean intermediate values. Thank you for pointing this out.

With that meaning, go with Daniel's answer.

Yes if the intermediate values of the addition/subtraction chain used in the computation of $kG$ are known, then it is straightforward to recover $k$. Recovery of the operands of the chain is equivalent to recovery of $k$.
To give an example, suppose that an addition chain such as you describe is being used to compute $10G$. There are four steps and let us write $G_1$, $G_2$, $G_3$ and $G_4$ are the intermediate values. For almost all addition chain methods used in practice, the next step is the sum of the newest point plus a previous one. The attacker pretty much knows for free that $G_1=G+G$ and then has to decide whether $G_2=G_1+G$ or $G_2=G_1+G_1$. This can be done exhaustively and then the attacker can decide whether $G_3=G_2+G$ or $G_3=G_2+G_1$ or $G_3=G_2+G_2$ by exhaustion. If there are $s$ steps in the chain, then $O(s^2)$ group operations are needed to exhaustively determine the chain. As $s=O(\log\ell)$ for the algorithms in use (here $\ell$ is the group order) the work is feasible.
Even if a completely generic addition/subtraction chain is used, there are at most $O(s^3)$ possible choices to exhaust over.


Can attacker recover private key if he know the algorithm and have the history of previous elliptic curve point coordinates, e.g. by using rainbow table?

Yes, there are multiple algorithms to compute $kG$, given $k$ and $G$.  However, they all generate the same result.
$kG$ is defined as $\underbrace{G+G+...+G}_{k \text{ times}}$.  This could be computed by simply adding $k$ copies of $G$ (however because of the size of $k$ we use, this is completely impractical).  These more "advanced" (that is, practical) algorithms rely on the fact that $aG + bG = (a+b)G$ (for any $a, b$), and so, for (to select a toy example) to compute $10G$, it may successively compute $G+G=2G, 2G+2G=4G, 4G+4G=8G, 8G+2G=10G$ or alternatively $G+G=2G, 2G+2G=4G, 4G+G=5G, 5G+5G=10G$.  Both addition chains [1] end up with $10G$; we discard the intermediate values, and so it is irrelevant which one we picked.
And so to answer your question: even if the attacker knew what algorithm we used to select an addition chain, it doesn't matter if all he sees the final result; that depends solely on the $k$ value we picked, and we're supposed to pick that randomly (and independently of any previous result).
The exception would be if the attacker would be able to listen into the algorithm while we're performing the algorithm.  This is a side channel attack, and if he is able to (say) distinguish between a "doubling" and an "addition" operation, that may give him sufficient information to deduce the $k$ value we picked - that depends on the algorithm we used to select the addition chain, and some algorithms are vulnerable to this and some are more resistant.
[1]: That's the term we give for the various successive additions that end up with a specific result.

Lets say that attacker only have intermediate values from following computation chain: $G+G=2G, 2G+2G=4G, 4G+4G=8G, 8G+2G=10G$, i.e. $2G, 4G, 8G, 10G$. The attacker do not know number $k$ in each of these intermediate values. Attacker eventually know that $4G$ have private key $k=4$. It does means that public key $10G$ have private key $k>=4$, and the attacker now have to do less computational effort to bruteforce public key $10G$.

@IvanStepanov: "It does means that public key $10G$ have private key $k \ge 4$" - actually, he might not.  Sometimes we deliberately use the property that ECAddition "wraps", that is, there is an $n$ with $aG = (a+n)G$ for all $n$, and so instead of computing $10G$ directly, we might actually compute $(10+\lambda n)G$ (for some moderate integer $\lambda$).  This is known as Coron blinding, and is sometimes used if we are concerned with side channel attacks.  And, of course, if Coron blinding is being used, the ultimate $k$ might be lower than intermediate values.

@IvanStepanov: of course, learning intermediate values of the addition chain may make computing the discrete log of the end target easier - without knowing which addition chain algorithm is being used, it's hard to make a firm statement.
